# Disable watch/ignore tag options in developer story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I accidentally ignored some tag while attempting to set keyboard focus with mouse into "Technologies" field:

[image]

Why should it be possible to discover new tags to watch or ignore tags while creating developer story?

"View tag" is useful, but it should force open link in new tab (I have experienced [another bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390845/1997232) because of this).

Answer (score 1):

This is a general tag description popup which allows you to do some stuff with the tag, including watching or ignoring it, from wherever you can see the tag. How is this particular case different?

Comment: I personally don't need that functionality while creating developer story, it may rather cause small issues. I thought it's a good idea to report. If, on the other side, someone will find it useful, then sure, keep it.